# Biber and accented characters

Tags: biber

I have the following entry in my bib-file which contains the accented character `\u\i`:

```
@article {Gur1966SpacesUniversalPlacement,
    author = {Gurari{\u{\i}}, V. I.},
     title = {Spaces of universal placement, isotropic spaces and a problem of {M}azur on rotations of {B}anach spaces},
   journal = {Sibirsk. Mat. \v{Z}.},
    volume = {7},
      year = {1966},
     pages = {1002--1013},
}
```

When I use BibTeX the correct entry is generated. Using Biber results in the following error message:

```
Undefined control sequence.
  Gurari{\ui 
                  }
```

It seems that the backslash in `\u\i` is removed. Is it possible to prevent Biber from doing this? Or more general, what is the proper way of using accented characters with Biber?

Comment: Just use the correct unicode character.

Comment: By the way, in an up to date version of biber, this should be resolved.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I tried to use the unicode character "ĭ" but then I ran into troubles with fontenc. It seems that `ĭ` is not in T1.

Comment: ĭ works fine for me with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. Perhaps your inputenc setting  and/or the encoding of the bib is faulty.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Apparently, Biber changes `\u{\i}` into `U+0131 U+0306` which of course confuses `pdflatex`. Here's what I see: `Gurari<C4><B1><CC><86>`

Comment: @egreg That \u{\i} doesn't work is not really a surprise, but the direct input ĭ should work if the (input) encodings are correct and correctly declared.

Comment: @Johannes_B Really? I still get errors if my `.bib` files contain accented characters in traditional input rather than their unicode equivalents. At least, I've certainly seen this very recently. (I tend to change the entries as I come across them when they cause problems, which only happens when they are actually cited. So I have a long-term supply of potential errors.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I am using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and I checked that my files are utf-8 encoded but I am getting the error: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ĭ not set up for use with LaTeX.` when I compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Sorry I meant `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in the above comment.

Comment: @user93559 The error `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ĭ not set up` means you have an older version of LaTeX. Update your TeX distribution. On the other hand, `Gurar{\u{i}}` should work; it's very unfortunate having to use different input, which makes code unportable. `:-(`

Comment: @egreg The problem with `Gurari{\u{i}}` is that `biber` seems to change it to `Gurari\ui`, i.e. it removes the second backslash and the parentheses.

Comment: @user93559 Update your TeX distribution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a strange combination of factors that should be solved by different people.

1. There's no predefined combination `\u{i}` in `t1enc.def`, so ĭ should be typed in as `\u{\i}`
2. Biber transforms `\u{i}` into `U+012D LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH BREVE`
3. Biber transforms `\u{\i}` into `U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I U+0306 COMBINING BREVE`

So the legal LaTeX input `Gurari{\u{\i}}` becomes a combination that makes sense to Unicode engines (XeTeX and LuaTeX) because of their normalization rules, but is pretty useless with `pdflatex`.

Solution: in the author field either type in

```
Gurar{\u{i}}
```

or

```
Gurariĭ
```

(the latter requires you load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: the problem goes beyond that - the second character (U+0131) does not have coverage on some very standard fonts, like for example, Times New Roman, so the following code, even under xelatex produces a square in the place of the accent: \documentclass{report} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \RequirePackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman} \begin{document} Oleı̆nik.  \end{document}

Comment: @PauloNey If a font doesn't have the necessary glyphs, it's not the fault of the maintainers of Biblatex. Please make a new question with the details.

Comment: @egreg You are my hero of the day! (+1 of course).