# Biber changing \u{\i} to some strange value

Tags: biber, unicode

Biber changes ASCII-TeX accents into their respective Unicode characters and while this works wonderfully well for most letters and accents -- it is a problem for accents on the "dotless i".

The problem resides on the fact that popular fonts like Times New Roman have coverage for the Unicode equivalent of

```
\u{i}
\"{i}
```

and do **not** have coverage for the Unicode equivalents of the "dotless"

```
\u{\i}
\"{\i}
```

even though under visual inspection they look exactly the same, as it can be seen on this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Accent on dotless with ASCII TeX: Ole\u\i nik,  Ha\"\i ssinsky

Accent on dotted i: Olĭnk, Haïssinsky

Accent on dotless i: Oleı̆nik, Haı̈ssinsky

\end{document}
```

Some of this is covered in EGreg's answer to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303821/biber-and-accented-characters/303829). The same problem happens with several other accents of dotless-i, but amazingly **not** with accent acute (\'{\i}).

I have a few questions on the subject:

How come the the ASCII-TeX input works for \u{\i} if there is no coverage for this character on the font? Is TeX making a substitution and using the dotted character in the final output?

Observe that converting sources to accents-on-dotted-i will obviously work for LaTeX and produce the right look into the PDF, but it is the wrong thing to do, since the sources may be used by other programs besides TeX or the sources may be coming from places that are not willing to make a wrong-change.

For an example on how biber deal with it use:

```
\documentclass{report}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{a,
    author = {Ole\u\i nik and  Ha\"\i ssinsky and Sina\^\i},
    title = {These display fine (dotted i):  Ole\u{i}nik and  Ha\"i{}ssinsky and Sina\^i},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: your descriptions are a bit misleading "Accent on dotted i" is a single character `U+00ef LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS`  and  "Accent on dotless i" is two characters `U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I` , `U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS`

Comment: Note that the two Unicode forms are not wrong or right, they are canonically equivalent, the single character version is in normal form "C" (NFC) and the two character version is in NFD, generally speaking NFC form is easier to handle as it does not required correct use of combining characters, but a full Unicode renderer will handle either form.

Comment: An example with a bib entry for a document using biblatex would make it possible to diagnose the issue, which seem to depend on how biber deals with `\u{\i}`

Comment: @egreg, I edited to include a full biber example.

Comment: I get the [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOsfy.png) with Biber version 2.10 and `biblatex` version 3.10.

Comment: I generally find that Biber only works properly if I use unicode characters in the `.bib` rather than macros. However, that's only for pdfTeX, which you're not using here and I'm not sure it would apply to a unicode engine.

Comment: There are way too many questions here for one question!

Comment: @egreg, indeed I am using TL 2017 that contain Biber 2.7 and biblatex 3.7. Will upgrade ... Any hunches on questions 4 and 5?

Comment: @PauloNey Biber only deals with particularly formatted files.

Comment: @egreg Yeahhh! It will not be good to jamm in and entire TeX file as the title of a paper, but depending on the routine it could be used independently.  I have tried placing some rather complex material in a .bib file and it seem to tackle it very well.

Comment: @egreg I just upgraded to biber  2.10 and biblatex 3.10 and I still see the same boxes in the place of the accented characters. I am using Times New Roman from the MS TTF Core Fonts packages. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @egreg I also installed "Times New Roman MT Std" from Adobe and with that one I get 4 characters missing (one more), so I would be deeply interested in what Time Roman exactly are you using.

Comment: Here is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/P3TbM0z.png

Comment: On my Windows 10 system the Times New Roman font (`times.ttf`, Monotype Co., version 6.98) displays all involved characters as expected. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864 and all the linked questions for Biber and the dotless i.

Comment: I absolutely agree with cfr here: You are asking way to many things in one question.

Comment: @PauloNey Do you get any “missing character” warning in the log file?

Comment: @egreg, Yes, I do get the report for the missing characters - like in: Missing character: There is no ̆ in font [times.ttf]/OT:mapping=tex-text;!

Comment: I guess @moewe gave the hint that solved the problem. It is tied to the version of the Times NR font from Monotype, and users of MS Windows will never see the problem which is Linux bound. I'll write a full answer.

Comment: @cfr I'll edit the question and move some of them out to new questions.

Comment: @PauloNey How can you typeset the name if the font doesn’t support the necessary glyphs?

Comment: @egreg - Well ... LaTeX typesets `\u{\i}` just fine, even with fonts that do not have this glyph.

Comment: @PauloNey I'd say this is not true: if a font doesn't have the precomposed ĭ or the breve accent (and the dotless i), the character will not be typeset.

Comment: @egreg The first file above (in the question) together with TimesNR from the  MSTTCoreFonts package is an exact example of this. `\"{\i}` gets typeset fine, but not `ı̈`.

Comment: @PauloNey Blame the CoreFonts package and use TeX Gyre Termes.

Comment: @egreg That is problematic ... specially when you have other fonts that are made to blend with Times NR and do not blend well with Termes. The solution is simply **get the new fonts** and I mentioned in the answer, but I am still puzzled by WHY LaTeX typesets on string and not the other -- since they are exactly the same glyph on the font.

Comment: My hunch is that in the case of `\"\i` is that the font had the dotless-i and has the umlaut and put the two of them together and in the case of `ı̈` the font does not have the particular glyph and TeX gives up. If this is indeed the case - it could be fixed. TeX knows how to put the characters together even if the ready-glyph is not there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer on why some accents are not showing, but not a full answer to the question brought up here. I still do not know why `\u{\i}` is typeset correctly even though the font is missing the glyph.

The problem of the glyphs entered in Unicode not being typeset properly is due to an old version of Times New Roman being distributed in the **Microsoft TrueType Core Fonts** package. The Version of Times NR being installed by that package is 2.95 which is too old and does not have the coverage for the accents on dotless-i.

From what I gather these old version of the fonts were distributed with a loose (or lousy) license and Microsoft has tightened it since.

What can you do to fix the problem?

1. **MS Windows** Users of (newer installations) MS Windows have the access to a fairly recent version of the font that do not show the problem.
2. **Linux dual-boot** You have the new fonts sitting in the Windows partition, just do a `locate times.ttf` and you can see it. Before copying them over to the Linux partition or using it within Linux -- you should consult the license.
3. **Linux by itself** Buy a recent version of the fonts from the foundry or a distributor like fonts.com